# How obvious is a psyker when using powers?

Tags: warhammer-40k, dark-heresy-2e

I play a psyker in Dark Heresy 2nd Edition and using mainly the Divination tree. What I want to know is if other characters or NPCs in visual or auditory range can notice that I am using a power, since this does not appear to be specified in the book.

I am aware that there are many powers that are VERY obvious when you use them, but I am more interested in the ones that are potentially discreet (like Divination or Telepathy for example), and I am also aware that another psyker could detect me with Psyniscience. I am mainly after how it works in Dark Heresy but I can accept answers from other W40k RPGs (Black Crusade, Only War etc.) or simply W40k lore.

Comment: We had a Psyker that was assisting in a pit fight, by throwing spasms at the enemy... it was all going great because no one could tell what was happening from the stands (and she was seated right next to the big bad boss) until she opened the warp, and exploded in a ball of warp lightning, killing 70% of the crowd outright... so it's 50/50.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a rule point, unless you have a visible effect on the peril of the warp and co. tables, nothing is visible.

From a lore point, most effect have some visible impact, the authors often mention a coldness when calling to the warp. On the other hand some obvious powers like Eisenhorn's command voice has just the uncanny tone and the reaction of most nearby.

As a GM I used to add some low key effect for drama when it had no mechanical impact : if everybody knows what the Imperial Diviner is doing, why not add a little something to the theatrics.